# Nexus 5,6 (Lollipop 5.1.1) Video view buffering time issue

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have an app in which two activities A,B. I navigate from A to B ,activity B have full screen videoview and plays HLS videos url like :  http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8

Now while video is buffering (not while playing) if user press back button and comes to activity A it freeze and ANR comes. with no other phone and OS version have this issue.

Tried to clear resources onStop() like this :

```
    mVideoView.suspend();
    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
    mVideoView = null;
```

Comment: am also facing the same issue, did you get the answer ??. Tried all the known possible way but nothing helped me

Comment: NO, Issue is still pending.

Comment: we used such trick to handle it, yet its performance hit :


 String deviceMan = Build.MODEL.toLowerCase();
 if     (deviceMan.contains(MyConstants.DEVICE_MODEL.toLowerCase())) {
      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

Comment: I used Exoplayer and worked it :)